# Relativistic energy in Lorentz force law

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, momentum

The covariant form of the Lorentz force can be written as

$$
\frac{dp^\mu}{d\tau} = qF^{\mu\nu}\eta_{\nu\alpha}u^\alpha
$$

(see [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force#Relativistic_form_of_the_Lorentz_force) for details).
In the low velocity limit, the vector version of this equation for the spatial coordinates $\mu={x, y, z}$ corresponds to the classical definition of the Lorentz force law, i.e. $\frac{d\mathbf{p}}{dt} = q(\mathbf{E} + \mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B})$.
However, what does the time component $\mu=t$ mean in the same limit?
I did some calculations, and I got

$$
\frac{dp^t}{d\tau} = qF^{t\nu}\eta_{\nu\alpha}u^\alpha = q(E_xu^x+E_yu^y+E_zu^z)
$$

which in the low-velocity limit becomes

$$
\frac{dp^t}{dt} = q\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{v}
$$

Are these right? If it is, I am still missing its meaning: what does this mean, physically?

Comment: That's power, energy (or work) per time unit.

Comment: @josephh. Eggman asked what $\frac{dp^t}{dt} = q\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{v}$ means physically. This is change of kinetic energy per time unit.

Comment: @md2perpe but it's relativistic energy, right? What bothers me is that one can write it as $p^t = \frac{m}{\sqrt{1-v^2}} = \gamma m$, which in low-speed limit becomes $p^t \sim m$, i.e. $\frac{dm}{dt} = q\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{v}$, and I don't really know how to make sense of this.

Comment: @Eggman See if my answer addresses your specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your derivation is correct.

And the equation with the time component of the momentum $$\frac{dp^t}{dt} = q\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{v}$$ is the rate in change of kinetic energy so it relates the mechanical work done on the particle by the electric field.

Note that  (with $c=1$) $$p^t=\gamma m=\frac{m}{1-v^2}=m(1-v^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$ and for $v\ll 1$ we can expand about $v=0$ so that $$p^t=m(1+\frac{1}{2}v^2 + \ldots)\approx m+\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$ meaning in the classical (low energy) limit the time component of the momentum is the sum of the mass plus the kinetic energy. We can write the relativistic kinetic energy $$E_k=E-m=\frac{m}{1-v^2}-m$$ where $E$ is the total energy.

Comment: Thank you, my error was to consider only the constant term in the energy expansion! I also forgot to mention that I was reasoning in the GR unit system.

Comment: That’s ok. Good luck with your studies.

Answer (score -1):

$p^0$ component is E/c, since $p^{\alpha }=\left(p_{0},p_{1},p_{2},p_{3}\right)=\left(\gamma mc,p_{x},p_{y},p_{z}\right)\,$ with $E= m\gamma c^2$ so it's power $\frac{d Energy}{dt} = q \,\pmb E \, \pmb v$. It means when a particle is moving in an E-Field the kinetic energy changes when work is done.